# Passing in different test starting points into TFS Release definition

Tags: c#, selenium, tfs, specflow

I have a Selenium/c#/specflow test project that is sitting locally and now on TFS.

The TFS version builds and picks up the tests fine, but I am currently using a hardcoded URL as the starting point for the tests.

I want to be able to create two different release definitions, one for the dev env and one for the test env.

I have found that there is a run settings file that can be added, and then overridden in the release definition (within the vstest assembly), but it seems this is geared towards unit tests.

My question is whether this is the correct place to specify a URL as the starting point for my tests (so that I can then create another release definition for dev and change this variable to my dev URL)? Is there a standard approach to doing this?

Ultimately I want to have a variable in my code for a URL, and to be able to over ride that from the release definition in TFS!

This is the first test project I've set up and built in TFS so I'm looking for a bit guidance on where this is best put.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if totally got your point, instead of hardcode the url in tests, you could try to use this solution which only requires:

· Create runsettings file and add your parameters.

· Modify your code to call the parameters from the .runsettings file

· Changes to the “Test Steps” in VSTS release or build

More details take a look at this blog: [Enabling Targeted Environment Testing during Continuous Delivery (Release Management) in VSTS](https://dondeetan.com/tag/selenium/)

Another blog may be helpful to set up your selenium test CD through TFS: [Continuous Delivery using VSO Release Manager with Selenium Automated Tests on Azure Web Apps (PaaS)](https://dondeetan.com/2015/10/13/continuous-delivery-using-vso-release-manager-with-selenium-automated-tests-on-azure-web-apps-paas/)

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for!